# Extracting Sum of Various Columns based on value in other Columns in a repetitive array of Data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to find the sum of all matching items in the following data for which sumif() is going to be very lengthy and need a shorter way of doing it

The data structure is as follows:

[image]

Here there are 20 items and hence a set of 4 columns repeats for every item.

Now, I want to get the total of items example
Item CA30  Total Item Qty = 10
Item CA10  Total Item Qty = 200

The new table should look like: (please ignore #N/A)

[image]

[Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18rUkErPOHqgda0RRCozXhyj482R1dAuXAqh_of2ejbA/edit?usp=sharing) to sample sheet

Comment: please share a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform) with example of your data and desired result.

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```cpp
=LET(data,REDUCE(TOCOL(,1),SEQUENCE(20,1,1,5),
             LAMBDA(a,i,VSTACK(a,CHOOSECOLS(Data!E2:CZ,SEQUENCE(2,1,i,3))))),
     MAP(B2:B37,LAMBDA(code,SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(data,,1)=code,INDEX(data,,2)))))
```

[image]

The first part of the formula is arranging the data in a usable format then we are performing a simple conditional sum using the `SUMPRODUCT` function.